# Create a project from bundle

Tags: git, symfony

I want to create a symfony project project from composer and from a sumfony bundle. 
here is how I imagined it'll work , please guide me:
I created a git repo in the bundle :
in /path/to/symfony/bundle

```
$ git init
```

then I created a server git in /usr/local/gitremote

```
$ git init --bare
```

I created a composer for my bundle as follows :

```
{
    "name" : "ng/mybundle",
    "description" : "Bundle for me",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "authors" : [{
        "name" : "Sekai",
        "email" : "admin@me.com"
    }],
    "keywords" : [
        "me bundle"
    ],
    "license" : [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "require" : {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "matthecat/htmlcompressor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "salva/jshrink-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Ng\\MeBundle" : ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir" : "Ng/MeBundle",
    "repositories" : [{}
    ],
    "extra" : {
    "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I commit all the files and when I clone it it works fine.
Now here is what I want to do : 
I want from my bundle only , to create the whole symfony project something in composer like

```
composer create-project ng/mybundle path/to/project
```

and it will install all dependencies including symfony.
Is this even possible ?